# Function call to dll causing program to hang

Tags: c#, wpf, dll

I have a problem where my code freezes at the point of calling a LogIn function in a Dll made to connect to an application on a server but it doesn't happen constantly. This only occurs when I LogIn and there is a connection followed by an attempt without connection that reconnects before a timeout(attempts LogIn repeatedly) and then attempt to LogIn again at this point it sits at the function call to the Dll forever. Each LogIn is followed with a LogOut once the data required is got from the server. This is the way the Dll function is brought in:

```
    [DllImport("SafeComDLLs\\scApi.dll",CharSet=CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    private static extern int sc_LoginByLogon(string szlpAddr,string szuserLogon,string szPassword);
```

This is the code I use to connect to the server:

```
    public int LogIn(string ipAddress, string userName, string password)
    {
        int result = -1;

        try
        {
             result = sc_LoginByLogon(ipAddress, userName, password);
             if (result == 0)
                 _log.Info("Log in Success");
             else
                 _log.Error("Log in failed, error message : " + result.ToString());
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            _log.Error("sc_LoginByLogon failed with exception : " + e.Message);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

As you can see I catch exceptions but as there is no exception thrown and the code just sits at this part:

```
         result = sc_LoginByLogon(ipAddress, userName, password);
```

Comment: What is your question about? Do you want to know how you can prevent this from freezing your UI?

Comment: The question is how do I stop LogIn from freezing at this point? Does the code have any errors in the way I am handling the function call from the Dll? The UI is separated and is only waiting for this to come back. Sorry Should have actually asked a question in the question.

Comment: As I can tell from here, the repeated calls to the native function might cause a deadlock. Maybe you want to lock the access so it cannot be called concurrently.

Comment: Thank you for the help but it was another part of the code that was causing the problem. I have also implemented your advice of creating a lock for access.